# How to increment a shell variable in an awk action

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

My shell script is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

global_var=0

func() {
 awk '$1 ~/^pattern/ {global_var=$((global_var+1))}' $1
}

func input_file_name
```

I want to increment the global (shell) variable `global_var` inside the `awk` action. How to do so? Normal shell style incrementing does not seem to be working.

Comment: In `awk` command, you just don't need to use `$` when accessing a variable.

Comment: @WKPlus: True in general, but the problem here is an attempt to access a _shell_ variable from inside an _`awk`_ program (using _shell_ syntax, but that's a secondary problem).

Comment: The problem is not only accessing a shell variable from inside an `awk` script, but also trying to modify the shell variable from inside an `awk` script.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
func() {
 awk '$1~/^pattern/ {++awk_var} END {print awk_var+0}' "$1"
}

shell_var=$(func input_file_name)
```

**The shell and `awk` are separate worlds, and you should treat them as such**(*) (which, in effect, you're already doing, by enclosing your `awk` program in *single* quotes, which prevents the shell from expanding any *shell* variable references in your `akw` program *string*).

Thus, **use an `awk`[-internal] variable to perform your counting (`awk_var`)** and output it after having finished processing the input file (in the `END` block, **using `print` to output the `awk` variable to `stdout`** - the `+0` part is to ensure that the output defaults to `0` in case NO match was found.)

Note that, generally, `awk` variables need no explicit initialization, because they default to `0` in numerical and Boolean contexts, and to `""` (empty string) in string contexts).

Also note that **`awk` has its own syntax**, and **shell constructs such as `$((...))` for arithmetic expansion do not apply**. Generally, `awk` variables are referred to *just by name* (no `$` prefix), and arithmetic operations such as `++` can be applied directly.

Using **command substitution - `$(...)` - in the shell then allows you to capture output from the `awk` command**.

In your specific case you have no need to pass variable values *into* the `awk` program, but if you needed to do that, you'd use one or more instances of  `awk`'s `-v` option; e.g.: `awk -v awk_var="$shell_var" ...`

On the shell (`bash`) side, if you wanted to *add* `awk`'s output to the shell variable instead of just *assigning* it:

```
declare -i shell_var                # make sure variable is an integer
shell_var+=$(func input_file_name)  # add function's output to existing value
```

---

(*) The **shell and `awk` have completely separate namespaces that have no direct way of interacting with one another: `awk` has no concept of shell variables, and the shell has no concept of `awk` variables.**

It is *technically feasible, but ill-advised* to integrate shell variable *VALUES* into an `awk` program - by using a *double*-quoted string to represent the `awk` program in which you reference *shell* variable *VALUES*, which are then expanded by the *shell* ONCE, BEFORE the string gets passed as a program to `awk`.
What you CANNOT do is to *modify* a shell variable from inside an `awk` program.

Since it gets complicated quickly as to which parts of the `awk` program are interpreted by the shell up front vs. which parts are interpreted by `awk` later (where `'$` has special meaning too, for instance), the **best approach** is to:

- use a *single*-quoted string to represent the `awk` program, so as to protect it from interpretation by the shell
- if values need to be passed *in*, use instances of the `-v` option
- if something needs to be passed *out*, print to `stdout` from `awk` and use command substitution or redirection to capture it via the shell.

Comment: If you `export global_var`,  then you could initialize `awk_var` from `ENVIRON["global_var"]`. Not saying it's a great idea, particularly since it is a one-way trip, but awk programs do have access to environment variables at least. Maybe that's just more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Not sure why you're using printf instead of print, but in any case it could be just `awk '$1 ~/^pattern/ {++awk_var} END {print awk_var+0}'`. +1 for the nice, detailed explanation.

Comment: @rici: That's an interesting alternative and good to know, but since it's a one-way street you may as well just use `-v ...`.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, and thanks for the `+0` tip - added to the answer. I used `printf` knowing that the result would be captured in a variable, but I agree that it may be confusing here (and is less safe in general without a format string), so I've switched to `print`.

Comment: I think the last statement should be `(( shell_var += $(func input_file_name) ))`. Or else awk should have `-v "awk_var=$shell_var"`.

Comment: @konsolebox: Thanks for the tip; I made the assumption based on the OP's code that determining the variable's value is _entirely_ performed in `awk`, with the shell variable only receiving the result. The body of my answer does mention how to pass in the current value with `-v "awk_var=$shell_var"` to demonstrate variable passing in general. With respect to your suggestion, I think using `+=` is the cleaner approach - I've added it to the answer, although I chose `declare -i` so as to not have to use `(( ... ))`.